# how to use if to create column of df

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
a<-c('TSPAN6','DPM1','SCYL3')
b<-c(0.1,0.001,0.0002)
c<-c(0.01,0.01,0.001)
d<-c(-0.5,1.3,-1.7)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c,d)
names(df)<- c('gene', 'p-val','padj','lfc')
```

I would like to create a new column based on conditional of the other columns.
Something like:

```
if (df$p-val < 0.01){
  df$new == 'black'
} else if (df$p-val<0.01 & df$padj < 0.01 & df$lfc<0) {
  df$new == 'blue'
} else if (df$p-val < 0.01 & df$padj < 0.01 & df$lfc > 0) {
  df$new =='red'
} else {
  df$new =='grey'
}
```

This doesn't work and I get

I have looked at similar posts to this but the answer always seems to be to use 'elsif' instead but I can't see how you can use 'elsif' with more than two conditions??

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: doesn't answer your question but you should change `p-val` as name, the`-` is used as a math operator in your example.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to check if there is any value on the column which is smaller, this could be achieved by using `any(df$p-val < 0.01)`. What you are doing is to check if every single value of the column is smaller then 0.01 which returns a vector with every result

`if([False True True])`, which doesn't make sense, so i just uses the first value

Answer (score 2):

You may use `within` with which you can manipulate variables of a data frame without the need to reference it all the time with `df$`. In the brackets `[` you create a logical subset (try e.g. `df$p.val < 0.01`), altogether only the `TRUE`s become a subset of the vector (which stands right before the `[`, e.g. `new[...]`). By assignment `<-` you may set e.g. everything to `"black"`.

```
df <- within(df, {
  new <- "grey"
  new[p.val < 0.01] <- "black"
  new[p.val < 0.01 & padj < 0.01 & lfc > 0] <- "blue"
  new[p.val < 0.01 & padj < 0.01 & lfc > 0] <- "red"
})
df
#     gene p.val  padj  lfc   new
# 1 TSPAN6 1e-01 0.010 -0.5  grey
# 2   DPM1 1e-03 0.010  1.3 black
# 3  SCYL3 2e-04 0.001 -1.7 black
```

***Note,*** that there are some issues with the code you tried. You said `df$new == 'black'` but actually meant `df$new = 'black'`. There's a fine distinction between `==` and `=`. `==` *compares* two elements, whereas `=` *assigns* something from the right to the left; that's why we rather use `<-` than `=` for assignment since it makes this more clear. Exception is within functions where we use `=` to set parameters.

Also as *@mischva11* already pointed out using operators such as `-`, `+`, `:`, `/`, `*` etc. is no good idea, in R we use `.` instead. Also avoid leading numbers, e.g. `20.sample` which would bring a lot of trouble.

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(gene = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("DPM1", 
"SCYL3", "TSPAN6"), class = "factor"), p.val = c(0.1, 0.001, 
2e-04), padj = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.001), lfc = c(-0.5, 1.3, -1.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This is great! I haven't seen 'within' again. Thanks alot